How can my full outer join work in mysql?
These images show the error
(https://i.sstatic.net/f7SAZ.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/bj0a1.png)
I am applying MySQL Query of Full Outer Join but unfortunately receiving an error
SELECT s.stu_name, g.grade
FROM students s
FULL OUTER JOIN grades g ON s.id = g.student_id;
I want this query to work

A full outer join is not possible in MySQL

MySQL supports the following JOIN syntax... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html -

Although MySQL does not [yet] support full outer joins natively, you can simulate them, by unioning an outer join with an anti-join.
The query becomes a longer but works as expected:
SELECT s.stu_name, g.grade 
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN grades g ON s.id = g.student_id -- first the outer join
UNION ALL
SELECT s.stu_name, g.grade 
FROM students s
RIGHT JOIN grades g ON s.id = g.student_id
WHERE s.id IS NULL; -- then the anti-join

